# What is the difference between "Arduino Remote" and "Arduino Wiring"

Tags: windows, arduino, iot, raspberry-pi3

When accessing an Arduino from Windows running on Intel chip (devices: Lattepanda, Udoo, Laptop) or Windows IoT running on Raspberry 3, what is the difference between "Arduino Remote" and "Arduino Wiring"?
Does Visual Micro's plugin for Visual Studio play any role in this decision? 
thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > What is the difference between "Arduino Remote" and "Arduino Wiring"?

"Arduino Wiring" is to enable the use(port) of existing Arduino Wiring sketches(projects) on IoT Core devices, with little efforts. Eventually, you deploy and runs your code on IoT devices, no Arduino devices is involved. Under the hood, it makes use of the direct memory mapped driver of your IoT device, so you need to have that enabled in the device portal or likewise.

Here is a nice tutorial to get started from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/lightning

"Arduino Remote", on the other hand, is to control your Arduino board through some means of communication protocols, USB, bluetooth, Wifi etc. It enables your UWP projects to have access to the various Arduino sensors with real ease by making use of the Windows Remote Arduino library.

You can find more information from  https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/win10/wralanding.

and 
https://github.com/ms-iot/remote-wiring